# Tea that lingers is more bitter, does it also contain more caffeine?

Tags: tea, caffeine

For convenience, I tend to brew tea in a French press. Just drop a bunch of tea leaves, add hot water, let the leaves dance in the water for a little while, and then push the press down and serve (I know there are probably a million better ways to do it, but take it as a given that I don't want to change my brewing method).

I tend to get two to three medium-sized cups from a single press. Unavoidably, because I drink these cups over the course of an hour or so, the last one comes from water that has lingered with the leaves longer and can be quite bitter, sometimes unpleasantly so.

If it was for the taste only, I would often pour that last cup down the drain. But I figure it might also be the cup with the highest caffeine content and because I also dring tea to stay alert through the day, I sometimes force that cup onto myself, for caffeine-intake purposes only.

Since this can be the only reason I go through that last cup, I am now wondering whether --- and to what extent --- it's even true that this last cup contains more caffeine than the previous ones? Am I at least getting the caffeine-intake benefits I am looking for when I chug that last disgustingly bitter cup?